# A CCK field that's a random number

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, random, cck

Anyone aware of a CCK module that adds a text field that's just a randomly generated number?

This means that when the user tries to create a fresh node, he sees a pre-populated random number as one of the fields (and can't change that field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Computed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field), which allows you to create fields whose values are defined by PHP snippets. For a random number, you might use something like this in your field's "Computed Code" configuration:

```
$node_field[0]['value'] = rand();
```

Note that rand() also accepts min and max arguments, in the form of rand(*min*, *max*).

Also be sure to enable the "Store using the database settings below" setting with a data type of "int" and a reasonable data length based on the expected range of values for rand(). This will ensure that the field isn't recomputed every time the node is displayed.

**EDIT:** I just realized that the above method stores a new random value each time the user updates/resaves the node. If you'd like the field to generate and store a random number once and only once for each node (at the node's initial save), try something like this instead:

```
if (!$node_field[0]['value']) {
  $node_field[0]['value'] = rand();
}
```

This will only set a value for the field if one doesn't already exist.